# How can I populate a panel from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have tried few ways around doing this however I can't seem to find one that will work. I have a GUI and when you press a button all the processing is done on a thread. For an example if I have the following code:

```
    public void coolMethod()
    {
        int a = 0;
        while (a != 20)
        {
            addPicturebox();
            a++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    int width = 3;
    int height = 3;
    int imgCounter = 0;

    public void addPicturebox()
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        pb.Location = new Point(width, height);
        pb.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\User1\Pictures\white.png";
        pb.Show();

        panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        imgCounter++;

        width += 53;

        if (imgCounter == 5)
        {
            height += 53;
            width = 3;
            imgCounter = 0;
        }
    }`
```

It will work however the `coolMethod()` is running on a different thread and I cannot update/add a control on panel from a different thread.

Does anyone have a solution whereby I can run the coolMethod on thread1 but once it calls the `addPicturebox()` this method will run on the gui thread AND pause the thread1 until the method is finished or any other suggestion.

Many thanks if you can. If this has been answered could you kindly link me too that page as I have looked through many but cannot find an example that will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing it is with a lambda invoke expression, just replace

```
addPicturebox();
```

with

```
panel1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
    addPicturebox();
}));
```

It also works like you want it to. The new threads gets paused until the controls get added

Comment: Wow that was a fast response and I have tried this and it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch Valjura

Comment: @Faker Accept the answer if it meets your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want to alter the GUI from another thread?

If that is the case, you need to use a Dispatcher

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
panel1.Invoke((Action)delegate { addPicturebox(); });
```